# How can I deploy a Elasticsearch on K8S with auto scale enabled?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am planning to deploy Elasticsearch to K8S. I deployed a `StatefulSet` pods which has `replicas: 3` configuration. That means there will be 3 pods deployed and I am hoping these 3 nodes will work as data nodes for Elasticsearch cluster.

But I got an error which is `[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`.

It means I need to specify all three hosts ip or name on ES configuration. But I'd like to enable auto scale on the ES cluster which means I don't know all the node name when I deploy. I'd like to make ES cluster pick up new node automatically. How can I achieve that?